# Every time I write any command with artisan, an error occured

Tags: php, project

Warning: require(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in artisan on line 18
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required './vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:') in artisan on line 18

Comment: Please follow the error message.

Answer (score 1):

did you run "composer install" command before running php artisan ?

Comment: I installed it but it is only installed :ahmedhesham@Ahmeds-MacBook-Pro ~ % composer install
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating autoload files
16 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!

Comment: It is not installed in cd example-app

Comment: @AhmedHesham you need to run composer install command in example-app directory. 1- cd example-app on cmd 2- Make sure you are inside example-app directory before running composer install command. 3. Run "composer install"